# Run a function after an asynch AJAX call has been made, passing through variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues with some code I'm working on. I have a generic function (`ajaxContent`) that is used from several points. What I need for this is a to run a function after the AJAX call has been made, but I need to pass though some data that I have before I made the call (so not data that comes back from the AJAX call.

```
function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, callbackFunction) {

  $.ajax({
    async : true,
    ....    
    complete: function(){
      if(typeof callbackFunction == "function"){
        callbackFunction(); // function get's executed here, lead_id is not available
      }
    }
  });
}    

$(document).on("click", "#something", function(){
  var leaf_id = $(this).attr('rel');

  ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, function(leaf_id){

    url = "/path/" + leaf_id;
    window.location = url;

  })
})

$(document).on("click", "#action", function() {

    ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, function(){

        if ($(this).attr('rel') == "M_0") // $(this).attr('rel') not available here, so need to pass through some way
            $('#treedata').css('background', 'url(/img/rotonde.png) 50% 50% no-repeat');
  });

});
```

I could perhaps use somehing like

```
function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, callbackFunction, varA, varB, varC, varD) { 
   callbackFunction(varA, varB, varC, varD);
}
```

with

```
ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, function(varA){
}, varA, varB, varC, varD)`
```

But not really scalable.

I hope this is clear :-)

Comment: based on your edit I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have in your answer now, `leaf_id` is a local variable inside the `document.ready()` handler function.  As such, it is not available outside that context.

You have several choices to fix that:

1. You can move the definition of ajaxContent function inside the `document.ready()` handler function so that it will be able to see leaf_id.
2. You can make `leaf_id` a global variable so it can be accessed from anywhere.
3. You can pass `leaf_id` to ajaxContent as a function argument.

Without more context about what you're doing, and because this is a transient value that is associated only with the particular action, I think the best option is #3:

```
function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, leafID, callbackFunction) {

    $.ajax({
        async : true,
    ....        
        complete: function(){
          if(typeof callbackFunction == "function"){
            // you can access any of the ajaxContent function arguments here
            callbackFunction(leafID);
          }
        }
    });
}       

$(document).on("click", "#something", function(){
  var leaf_id = $(this).attr('rel');

  ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, leaf_id, function(leafID){

    url = "/path/" + leafID;
    window.location = url;

  })
})
```

Or, if you have lots of variables to pass through, you can create an empty object and then put each variable as a property on that object and then just pass the single object into ajaxContent and into your callback like this:

```
function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, settings, callbackFunction) {

    $.ajax({
        async : true,
    ....        
        complete: function(){
          if(typeof callbackFunction == "function"){
            // you can access any of the ajaxContent function arguments here
            callbackFunction(settings);
          }
        }
    });
}       

$(document).on("click", "#something", function(){
  var args = {};
  args.leafID = $(this).attr('rel');

  ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, args, function(settings){

    // access args.leafID here
    url = "/path/" + leafID;
    window.location = url;

  })
})
```

Note, in my code example, I named the argument something different than the other variable to avoid confusion about which is which.

Comment: Exactly correct :-) but is there no way to pass this through via the `ajaxContent` call?

Comment: @Richard - I've made three suggestions for ways to solve this.

Comment: I could perhaps use somehing like `ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, leaf_id, function(varA){}, varA, varB, varC, varD` with `function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, leafID, callbackFunction, varA, varB, varC, varD) { callbackFunction(varA, varB, varC, varD);` But not really scalable.

Comment: @Richard - Are you trying to solve the problem for N variables?  If so, then create an empty object and put each variable as a property on the object and then pass just the one object through to `ajaxContent` and to your callback.  You can even add more properties to it in ajaxContent before passing on to the callback if you want.  This is much more scalable and extensible if you have lots of arguments.  I added an example of this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`leaf_id` is undefined, because you are not passing any arguments when calling `callbackFunction();`.

You can pass variables through callbacks but you need to pass it all the way, here is how you could write your code to make `leaf_id` get passed along:

```
function ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, callbackFunction, leaf_id) {
    $.ajax({
        async : true,
    ....        
        complete: function(){
          if(typeof callbackFunction == "function"){
            callbackFunction(leaf_id);
          }
        }
    });
}

ajaxContent(url, id, target, data, function(leaf_id){
    url = "/path/" + leaf_id;
    window.location = url;
}, $(this).attr('rel'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qaWNp/2/

Comment: I have updated my question with some code. An issue here is that the callback function is different for each usage. So differt number of variables.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I can find a scalable solution for my solution like this, as there are a bunch of different callback functions used, with a different number (and names) of variables. 'leaf_id' was just an example in this case.